# issues with npm start

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, package.json

Trying to run a React project I haven't touched in a week or so. When I run 'npm start' the project doesn't show up in my browser automatically anymore. My terminal says that it's being served locally. When I pasted in the address, it didn't show up and I received a 'not found' error . After about 5 min I tried again, and now the project shows up on localhost:5000. I am curious though as to why 'npm start' isn't automated like it should be with React. I tried making changes to my project, and the app in my browser isn't responding to any changes I'm making, even with a hard refresh. So far I've tried deleting node_modules and re-installing npm. I haven't found a thread on npm start that addresses this particular issue, so any advice is appreciated. [image: serving]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out. For some reason the script for running in my
package.json changed to
 `"start": "serve -s build"` I changed it to `"react-scripts start"` and that seemed to fix the problem. Not really sure what made it change in the first place.